# Use goroutines in combination with buffered reading to optimize reading a large file

Tags: go

Given a requirement where a large csv file (about 300 bytes long lines ending in /n) needs to be processed in a typical [ETL: Extract, Transform, Load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) fashion (each line read, split and composition of a JSON inserted in a DB). Would it be beneficial to spawn one (or more) goroutines that worked together processing the file?
What would need to be done to create a `bufio.Scanner` that started reading from a random position of the file?

Comment: The slowest part here will be likely inserting in DB. Use batched inserts if your DB supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be beneficial to spawn one (or more goroutines)?

Yes, absolutely. In general, you could have 3 concurrent goroutines on each E, T, L, and have them coordinated via channels.

For more insights, check out this awesome talk from Rob Pike himself:

`Concurrency is not Parallelism`: https://goo.gl/cp8xgF
`Talk Slides` http://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#1

Comment: Thanks for sharing the talk by Rob Pike, really deep and IMO a must see if you want to use Go properly

Comment: Unfortunately the linked video is now gone because the account was terminated, however the video's official home (given in the slides) appears to be: https://vimeo.com/49718712